# Not able to store data into database in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I've tried a lots of method to insert my data into joomla database but it's not working. Even though i have readed previous questions that has been asked by other stackoverflow members but still it is not solving my problem and also tried to understand the official joomla website but all goes in vain. Below is my code:-

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

   $app =& JFactory::getDocument();
   $page_title = $app->getTitle();

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];


   $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
   echo $query = "INSERT INTO ' k2store'.'os0fr_jd'('id','name', 'class')
                  VALUES ('','$name','$class')";
                  mysql_query($query);
   $db->setQuery( $query );
   $db->query(); 







?>
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="adminForm">
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_sms" />
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="Sms" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name">
Class:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="class">
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="register">
</form>
```

Please help me to know my mistakes and any help will be appreciated the most...

Comment: Nope, i didnot got any error messages

Comment: You aren't doing any error handling in this, so you may still have errors, but aren't seeing them. I haven't used joomla; however, after skimming through their docs, it appears you have this method available to you: `getErrorMsg`. You could try adding this to your code: `$err = $db->getErrorMsg(); echo $err;`

Comment: Hmm , I have tried it now but still it's not showing me any kinds of error..

Comment: Another thing is that you shouldn't have these in single quotes: `VALUES ('','$name','$class')` because it will treat it as a string, '$' and all.

Comment: Thanks @Nicarus, now eveything has been working well....thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

So finally i have managed to found it's solution. Below is the updated code :-

```
    <?php
/**
 *
 * @file        $Id: default.php 0.0.2 2012-12-28 00:00:00 Joydeep Banerjee $
 * @package        School Mangement System 
 * @version     0.0.2
 * @description Simple School Management System component for joomla 2.5
 * @copyright      Copyright Â© 2012 - All rights reserved.
 * @license          GNU General Public License v2.0
 * @author          Joydeep Banerjee
 * @author mail    joy@vividtechno.com
 * @website          http://www.indiawebsitedesigndevelopment.com
 *
 **/

  // No direct access
  defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
       $app =& JFactory::getDocument();
       $page_title = $app->getTitle();

       echo $name = $_POST['name'];
       echo $class = $_POST['class'];


       $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
echo $query = "INSERT INTO `#__jd` (`id`,`name`, `class`)
    VALUES ('','$name', '$class');";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query(); 
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="adminForm">
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_sms" />
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="Sms" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name">
Class:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="class">
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="register">
</form>
```

The main problem was that i forgot to put ` in name and also '' in $name and $class which was stated by the Nicarus(A Stackoverflow member). Thanks for the reply..:)